# php return array key of first element?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an assoc array in PHP which I am sorting by value. After sorting I need to return the key of the first element.

Example array:

```
Array
(
    [a] => 42.857142857143
    [b] => 87.5
    [c] => 50
    [d] => 61.538461538462
)
```

Then I use asort(), and the array looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [b] => 87.5
    [d] => 61.538461538462
    [c] => 50
    [a] => 42.857142857143
)
```

How can I return "b" (as it is the key of the first array)?

Comment: Whoops, misread.  Can't delete.  Disregard. :)

Comment: @SenorAmor - nick of time ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `key()` in combination with `reset()` to make sure you have the first element:

```
reset($arr);
$key = key($arr);
```

Comment: Now the only question is which came first, the key or the array? :D

Comment: I tried it and key is empty in my case. :(  *Edit: If I understand the php.net documentation, reset returns a string, and so I can't get the key from a string.

Comment: @koljanep You're right, that was too fast, you need to reset the array seperately and then get the key, see my edit: http://codepad.viper-7.com/23fMsh

Answer (score 3):

`reset()` the array pointer to the first item and then call `key()`.

```
reset($array);
$key = key($array);
```

Or you can use `array_keys()`.

```
$array_keys = array_keys($array);
$key = $array_keys[0];
```

Comment: +1 You were right, you need to do it in two steps. I wonder why it was downvoted though...